# sed + delete function from bash file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

we want to add some function as `rm` function to `bashrc` , and after some configuration to remove the function `rm`

so first the following described the approach how to add the function `rm` to `bashrc`

```
echo '
function rm
{
echo "ERROR rm command not allowed on this machine"
return 1
}
' >>/root/.bashrc
```

and then reload

```
source /root/.bashrc
```

in some stage in our scripts we need to do the opposite approach - delete the function `rm`

```
function rm
{
echo "ERROR rm command not allowed on this machine"
return 1
}
```

so I create the following `sed`

```
sed -i '1,/function/p;/}/,$p' /root/.bashrc
```

but I not so feel good with above approach -  deletion the function

I will appreciate to get better approach to delete the function rm, from `/root/.nashrc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is the only `function rm` line in your bashrc file, you could initially do a dry run

```
$ sed '/function rm/,/}/d' /root/.bashrc
```

If happy with it, then add the `-i` flag.

If the above is true and as you know the amount of lines inserted, you could also use this approach.

```
$ sed '/function rm/,+4d' /root/.bashrc
```